# Changing value in Edittext

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a little app were the user needs te scan a QRcode from a product to register how much of this product he used.
I want the user to have the possbility to put in the value from the code manually, becuase the QR is printed on a piece of papier that gets easily damaged.
I have implemented a barcodescanner using ZXing, and I am able to open this.
However, when I scan a code and want to assing the value of it to my EditText field, I get the folowing error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: be.jacops.juniorvandamme.verbruikpxs, PID: 29933
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at be.jacops.juniorvandamme.verbruikpxs.ActivityQr.handleResult(ActivityQr.java:59)
                  at me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView$1.run(ZXingScannerView.java:148)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

This also results in the app crashing.
The code from this activity is the folowing:

```
package be.jacops.juniorvandamme.verbruikpxs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.zxing.Result;

import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class ActivityQr extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    Button btnToUsage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
        btnToUsage = findViewById(R.id.btnToUsage);
        btnToUsage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                EditText txtNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
                String strNumber = txtNumber.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strNumber)){
                    txtNumber.setError("Geef een Bobijnnummer in, of scan de QR code.");
                    return;
                } else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityUsage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void qrScanner(View view){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityUsage.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void handleResult(Result rawResult){
        final EditText txtNumber = findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
        String txtTemp = rawResult.getText().toString();
        Log.e("QRcapture", txtTemp);
        txtNumber.setText(txtTemp);
    }
}
```

The XML file for this is the folowing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityQr">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToUsage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Volgende"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.68" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnToScanner"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Gebruik de scanner"
        android:onClick="qrScanner"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnToUsage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Geef het bobijnnummer in."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="@string/bobijnnummer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnToScanner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.697" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've been looking for a fix all day searching on multiple sites (one of which is here). I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 1):

try declaring your fields outside any particular method. In this case declare your `EditText` outside `onCreate` and assign the reference inside it rather than inside the listener. I think this is a scope error as the reference is not assigned at runtime when the call is made.